# USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Tags: python-3.x

I am making an automatic youtube viewer software.
BUT when I run the code I get an error

```
[7856:3848:0628/112843.870:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:28:43.869] USB:     usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[7856:3848:0628/112843.871:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:28:43.871] USB:     usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
PS C:\Users\Long\he\sesison4> [7856:1700:0628/112941.446:ERROR:util.cc(127)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
[7236:5288:0628/113041.419:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Here is my code python

```
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.code)

    def code(self):
        P = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        U = open(P, mode = "r")
        L = U.readline()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Chormedriver\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.set_window_size(700,800)
        driver.get(L)
        time.sleep(3000)
```

Hope everybody help please.